# Referencing Foreign Key to a Corrupted Column

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server in Visual Studio 2022 and I have a problem creating a table which uses a foreign key referencing to a corrupted column in another table

Here is the first table

```
CREATE TABLE ProductTable
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ProductID AS 'P' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) PERSISTED,
    ProductName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Price INT NOT NULL,
    SupplierID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SupplierTable(SupplierID),
    PRIMARY KEY(ProductID)
)
```

This one is the table that I am trying to create

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Supplier
(
    ProductID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProductTable(ProductID),
    ProductName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProductTable(ProductName),
    SupplierID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SupplierTable(SupplierID),
    SupplierName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SupplierTable(SupplierName),
    LessPercentage VARCHAR(10)
)
```

These worked before as I restarted Visual Studio 2022 and I don't know why it does not work anymore. I have already counted the possible length of ProductID.ProductTable which is 5 (or idk if im wrong) that's why the length of the second table is VARCHAR(5).

I am getting the error

> Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

ProductID in both tables should have the same data column definition.

The Product_Supplier table defines the ProductID as VARCHAR(5).

The ProductTable appears to define the ProductID as something else.

Comment: but if I defined ProductID in ProductTable as VARCHAR(5), data under it won't be "P0001", "P0002"... I don't know why it did not work for the Product_Supplier table because it worked for another table before creating this one.

Comment: @Hanuki PS - What column data type is generated for the ProductTable? Is it VARCHAR(5) or something else? There must be some difference that needs to be reconciled.

Comment: Table definition does not show its data type, it is something else. I made this a corrupted column so that it would auto increment whenever a new row is added. I casted VARCHAR(4) to "P" so it makes "P0001"...

Comment: The computed column is (implicitly) defined as a `varchar(5)`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6McYZfNB)

Comment: @Hanuki PS - Can you append "AS VARCHAR(5)" to the ProductID column definition for the ProductTable?

Comment: @JohnH - 'VARCHAR' is not recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Hanuki PS - I suspect that the foreign key will work if the ProductID column in the ProductTable is defined as just VARCHAR(5). There may have been a change with VS 2022 that produced this new error. If so, another method of populating the values of the ProductID column may need to be found.

Comment: yeah I may need to find another method of populating the values of ProductID column, thanks for the effort John! I appreciate it.